# How to insert item at the top of Combo Box?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql

Hi I am using Linq to SQl to bind the combo box control. How can i add a item at the top of the list of combo box?

```
var items = from c in db.Contacts
                               orderby c.Name ascending
                               select c;
                if (items.ToList().Count > 0)
                {
                    cmb1.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
                    cmb1.DataSource = items;
                    cmb1.DisplayMember = "Name";
                    cmb1.ValueMember = "ID";
                }

                cmb1.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
```

This above code is failing.

Comment: What does it fail on? It seems pretty okay...

Comment: Can't insert the item after data binding...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way would be to insert the "--Select--" contact place-holder into the results before binding:

```
     var items = (from c in db.Contacts
                  orderby c.Name ascending
                  select c).ToList();

     items.Insert(0, new Contact { ID = 0, Name = "--Select--" });

     cmb1.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
     cmb1.DataSource = items;
     cmb1.DisplayMember = "Name";
     cmb1.ValueMember = "ID";
```

Or you could do the same thing with an anonymous version of the results:

```
     var items = (from c in db.Contacts
                  orderby c.Name ascending
                  select new { c.ID, c.Name }).ToList();

     items.Insert(0, new { ID = 0, Name = "--Select--" });

     cmb1.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
     cmb1.DataSource = items;
     cmb1.DisplayMember = "Name";
     cmb1.ValueMember = "ID";
```

Answer (score 2):

As you noted in your own comment to your question, you can't insert an item after data binding.

One option would be to use [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386979.aspx) to concatenate a sequence containing your "Select" item with the results of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the --Selected-- item not directly to the combo.items collection but to the items list that you binded to the combo.

```
List = linq query;
List.Insert(0, "--Select--");

combo.Datasource = List;
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above does not work. I tried all and end up  with the below. Linq query output enumerables and lists seems to be immutable like Arrays

I hope your requirement satisfies the below

cbo.Items.Clear();

```
        Region optAll = new Region { RegionName = "All", RegionId = 0 };

        var qOrg = (from rows in LDC.Regions orderby rows.RegionName 
                    select new
                        {
                            rows.RegionId,
                            rows.RegionName
                        }).ToList();
        if(needAll)
            cbo.Items.Add(optAll);

        foreach (var region in qOrg)
        {
            cbo.Items.Add(region);
        }

        cbo.DisplayMember = "RegionName";
        cbo.ValueMember = "RegionId";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a blank selection at the top of list after bound to combo box OnLoad. EF 6

```html
db.Users.Load();
var updateList = db.Users.Local.ToBindingList();  updateList.Inset(0, new User { ID=0, UserId = "" });    this.userComboBox.DataSource = updateList}
```