# Adding default value to ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I have a windows application that is using a `ComboBox` which previously had the 'Edit Items' filled out by hand.  I am changing this to grab the data from a `Database table`.

How do I add a blank value so they must selected an option?

Currently it automatically shows the first person returned from the `dataset` in the `comboBox` I'm wondering how I force it to show a blank value as the default?

Designer generated code.

```
    // attorneySelectDropDown
    // 
    this.attorneySelectDropDown.DataSource = this.jMeFileAssignAttorneyBindingSource;
    this.attorneySelectDropDown.DisplayMember = "name";
    this.attorneySelectDropDown.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    this.attorneySelectDropDown.FormattingEnabled = true;
    this.attorneySelectDropDown.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 15);
    this.attorneySelectDropDown.Name = "attorneySelectDropDown";
    this.attorneySelectDropDown.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(298, 21);
    this.attorneySelectDropDown.TabIndex = 4;
    this.attorneySelectDropDown.ValueMember = "name";
    this.attorneySelectDropDown.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: There is no code to show @MikeSchwartz.  Everything was set up through the Design menu buttons through assigning it a DataSet.  The Dataset pulls the name from a table, name is assigned to DisplayMember and ValueMember.

Comment: You can save the values returned from the database in a list, then add a new "blank" item to the list, and bind the ComboBox to this list.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange - I don't think you even need to do that; you just need to add the blank item before the databinding. [See this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518233/how-to-insert-item-at-the-top-of-combo-box).

Comment: Is the only way to do this through using the code behind, no way I can do it and use the design menu items built into the designer? @PoweredByOrange.

Comment: @JamesWilson - Given the designer just generates code, what's the problem with directly editing the source?

Comment: @admdrew As you can see in the accepted answer on the link you gave, the data is being stored in a separate list, and then is being databound.

Comment: @admdrew I'll add the snippet of code from the designer.

Comment: What is `this.jMeFileAssignAttorneyBindingSource`? Can you add a blank item to it before you call `this.attorneySelectDropDown.DataSource = this.jMeFileAssignAttorneyBindingSource;`?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange that is the name of the datasource that is creating the list to be put into the ComboBox.  I tried to .Item.Add but it said I could not modify the items property when the DataSource is set.

Comment: @JamesWilson As I said, you need to add the item to the `jMe` list BEFORE you set the datasource.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Ok, but I'm not sure how to do that as it isn't an option that I can see doing this through the form designer.  If it isn't possible to do it through the designer which seems silly, then I just wont worry about it I guess.  I've tried jMeFileAssignAttorneyBindingSource.Add, .AddNew, .Insert.  And no matter what the only data that shows in the combobox is the data returned from the Dataset.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After `Fill` method, you should set `SelectedItem` property to null:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'stackoverflowDataSet.Person' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.personTableAdapter.Fill(this.stackoverflowDataSet.Person);
    comboBox1.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

In this case user have to select item from ComboBox.

Comment: This seemed to do the trick, the only caveat is it fires the ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged event with a null value.

Comment: Yeah this causes additional errors down the road, it's very close to what I need however, it would be perfect it it didn't fire the IndexChanged event.

Comment: @JamesWilson so you should check in `ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler if `SelectedItem` is not equal to null. `if(comboBox1.SelectedItem != null) { //do something...}`