# Default value for combo box using enum datasource

Tags: c#, combobox

I want to add a default value for a C# ComboBox but cant without 6 plus lines of code. The ComboBox gets its fields from an Enum using the code below

I have researched and have seen only solutions that seem to require too many lines of code or are too complicated.

`accountComboBox.DataSource = AccountType.GetValues(typeof(AccountType));`

research suggests I would need to do something like this to add a default value to the drop down combo box

```
tbl.Columns.Add("UnitName");
tbl.Rows.Add("item 1");
tbl.Rows.Add("item 2");
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.DataSource = tbl;
ddl.DataMember = "UnitName";
ddl.DataTextField = "UnitName";
ddl.DataBind();

//add new item
ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("inserted item"));
```

Is there a simpler solution like in java which simply uses: 
`jComboBoxAccount.setRenderer(new PromptComboBoxRenderer("-Select Account Type-"));`

Comment: You can insert item at top of the combo box after databinding. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518233/how-to-insert-item-at-the-top-of-combo-box

Comment: ok i guess thats the only solution. Why does it require so much code to do? I guess I could add a default value to my Enum but that just doesnt seem right.

Comment: You can insert new item after doing `accountComboBox.DataSource = AccountType.GetValues(typeof(AccountType));`. It's only one extra line of code. you don't need to create table.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya how do I do this? How do I insert a new item to a ComboBox whos datasource is an Enum?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya how do I do this? How do I insert a new item to a ComboBox whos datasource is an Enum?